# How to gather images from the web of classes you want to train but don't have images of

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, dataset, training-data

I have been asked about providing a solution to classifying images of wildlife captured by camera traps. I have found some models that are trained on a variety of animals, but there are a lot of species in the are that the models are not trained to classify.

I would like to know what the best way is to gather images of that species in order to train the model without having to manually capture the images myself. The images that google presents when you search for the species you want to classify seem to be good and there are enough, but is there an efficient and legal way of using these images? Or is there another database maybe?

I am new to the industry so it would be great to know how others tackle this issue when/if they are faced with it.

I looked at a bunch of models available for free, and I looked at the species that they are trained to classify. They classify some of the species in the specific are, but not all.

Answer (score 0):

Recently [laion-5B](https://laion.ai/blog/laion-5b/) was released and is a great place to look for training images.

Given that there are 5 billion images in the dataset you're likely to find at least some images of many different species. Each image comes with an associated text description which can be used to do string searches for images of specific species.

If you want to try it out they provide a [search demo](https://rom1504.github.io/clip-retrieval/?back=https%3A%2F%2Fknn5.laion.ai&index=laion5B&useMclip=false) which you can use to check what kind of data is in the dataset. And then you can download the dataset from [HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/laion) to programmatically query the data and download the images if you think it's useful.

Regarding the legality of using this data. I have no idea.